# ¿Como puedo agrupar los resultados de mi consulta que tengan el mismo ID?

Tags: java, sql

Buen día,
Realizo una consulta donde obtengo la cantidad de piezas vendidas por día y necesito desplegarlo en una tabla con las ventas semanales. La situación es que necesito que no se repitan los clientes en la tabla, y que me muestre todos los registros de la semana por cliente en la misma fila, anexo el código y la manera en que me despliega los datos.

```
SELECT razon_social,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-05-30' THEN no_garrafones END L,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-05-31' THEN no_garrafones END M,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-06-01' THEN no_garrafones END M,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-06-02' THEN no_garrafones END J,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-06-03' THEN no_garrafones END V,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-06-04' THEN no_garrafones END S
          
    FROM entregas
    WHERE fecha IN ('2022-05-31','2022-05-30','2022-06-01','2022-06-02','2022-06-03','2022-06-04' ) AND sector = 'sector'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, resulta un poco difícil escribirte la sentencia necesaria para obtener el resultado esperado sin conocer la estructura de las tablas. Sin embargo creo que podrías utilizar `group by`, te dejo un enlace a la documentación de dicha instrucción [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Esto se puede resolver fácilmente con [una búsqueda en Google sobre como agrupar datos](https://bfy.tw/TB0s)

Comment: Puedes intentar agrupando por el ID de cada cliente o por razón social e incluso agrupar por ambos ID y razón social. Prueba que te funciona mejor.

Comment: Hola! gracias por las aportaciones pero ya había intentado con Group by y no da solución al problema, la situación es que las columnas L,M,Mi.. etc no forman parte de la tabla, es un conjunto de varias consultas para sacar el reporte de ventas semanal. todo se obtiene de una sola tabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día, lo que necesitas es una agrupación, yo agregue un "sum" por si hay datos repetidos, espero te sirva

```
select razon_social,sum(L)L,sum(M)M,sum(Mi)D,sum(J)S,sum(V)V ,sum(S)S 
from 
(
    SELECT razon_social,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-05-30' THEN no_garrafones END L,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-05-31' THEN no_garrafones END M,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-06-01' THEN no_garrafones END Mi,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-06-02' THEN no_garrafones END J,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-06-03' THEN no_garrafones END V,
           CASE WHEN fecha = '2022-06-04' THEN no_garrafones END S
          
    FROM entregas
    WHERE fecha IN ('2022-05-31','2022-05-30','2022-06-01','2022-06-02','2022-06-03','2022-06-04' ) AND sector = 'sector'
)a
group by razon_social
```

Comment: Funciono muy bien, muchas gracias !!